# argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime

Tags: python, time, mktime, python-datetime

Web app is breaking on the following line;

```
start_time = int(time.mktime(start)) * 1000
```

The error is a TypeError - argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime

How to I convert my datetime.datetime to a 9-item-sequence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of passing `datetime` object directory, use [`datetime.timetuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple) method:

```
>>> int(time.mktime(start)) * 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime

>>> int(time.mktime(start.timetuple())) * 1000
1406215043000L
```

BTW, if you use Python 3.3+, you don't need to use `time.mktime`. Use [`datetime.timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

```
>>> start.timestamp()
1406215043.0
>>> int(start.timestamp()) * 1000
1406215043000
```